# c draw function not drawing properly

Tags: c, draw

I'm trying to write a program that writes a digital car speedo onto an LCD screen (ST7735) with a Tiva C (Tm4C123GXL). The attached code is the draw line function that should draw a straight line between the two distances. if I put in (speed_x1, speed_y1, 80, 60, ST7735_WHITE) into the function, up until 45 degrees, the line drawn is horizontal, not angled like it should be. After 45 degrees up until 90, the drawing is fine, then after 90 it breaks again.

```
speed_x1 = 80 - 55 * cos((PI / 180) * (speed * 1.8))
speed_y1 = 60 - 55 * sin((PI / 180) * (speed * 1.8))
```

(I want the speedo to max out at 100, hence speed * 1.8 is 1.8 degress/km/hr)

Any help in solving my problem here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
 void ST7735_DrawLine(short x1, short y1, short x2, short y2, unsigned short color) {
        // unsigned char hi = color >> 8, lo = color;
        //int x=x1;
        //int y=y1;

        int dy = y2 - y1;
        int dx = x2 - x1;
        double m = dy / dx;
        double c = y1 - m * x1;
        if ((x1 >= _width) || (y1 >= _height) || (x2 >= _width) || (y2 >= _height) ) return; 
        setAddrWindow(x1, y1, x1 + x2 - 1, y2);
        while(x1 <= x2)
        {
            if (m <= 1)
            {
                x1 = x1 + 1;
                y1 = m * x1 + c;
                ST7735_DrawPixel(x1,y1,color);
            }
            else
            {
                y1 = y1 + 1;
                x1 = (y1 - c) / m;
                ST7735_DrawPixel(x1,y1,color);
            }
        } 
    }

void ST7735_DrawPixel(short x, short y, unsigned short color) {
    if ((x < 0) || (x >= _width) || (y < 0) || (y >= _height))
        return;
    setAddrWindow(x,y,x+1,y+1);
    pushColor(color);
}
```

Comment: Why do beginers allways add both, `C` and `C++` tag? Do use `stdint.h` for types of certain size. Slso, for the tivia, best size for arguments would be `(u)int32_t` as this is a 32 bit CPU, not 16 bit types which short normally would be. Also: what have you done to get the error. Do you have any specific question? "Why does my code not run" is too broad; note that most ppl here will not have that hardware. If that would be a bresenham line drawing algorithm note that it normally requires reordering of the coordinates if the line is not within 0-45 degree (base/dir depend on implementation).

Comment: Note that you would safe a compare for negative values if you use uint32_t for the coordinates. Standard warning: UB if you cast signed negative to unsigned!

Comment: my specific question was that "Why does it draw a horizontal line when it should be an angled line?" But it looks like I may need to break it down into 45 degree sections and code for each one

Comment: I made that an answer. However, no  halfway experienced developer would implement it the way you did. Start with removing the doubles (the tivia only has a single prec FPU; double is pretty expensive and completely unnecessary). You actually would get along as good with uint32_t which is still faster than float.

Comment: Yeah I've never used Tiva before, I don't like firmware and probably won't ever touch it again after this uni assignment

Comment: Funny, I do prefer to have all strings in _my_ hands. However, that is actually not a firmware problem; it would have been solved on high-level pretty much the same. Also, how you handle a task you actually do not like show much more than your programming skills. You're still thinking in your job later you will be able to do only tasks you like? Not unless your profession will be  "son (of rich parents)". If someone working for me would show that attitude, she would really have a problem with the whole team. This attitude is just unprofessional.

Comment: There is no "c/c++". Unless your program is actually written in a mix of languages, please pick one.

Comment: @Olaf: Casting to an unsigned type never causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @n.m Fixed the tags and title. now just says c

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks for making me read the standard. Seems to be not that simple as just transfering the bit-representation in general. But obviously this is tailored for 2's complement representation as only for this conversation it actually _is_ just a transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecast problem. M results in 0 when dy/dx is below one. Typecast them to floats to get a float as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If that would be a [bresenham line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) note that it only works within 45 deg. (Always wonder why ppl not even have a look at WP first.)
Not sure, but as your surname has a german origin: you will also find this in german on WP.

For other angles you would have to swap/reorder coordinates. It might even be better to have seperate drawing algorithms for hor/vert and diagonal lines, if performance is an issue (but as you use double, it is obviously none at all).